# NoneType has not attribute Group

Tags: python, python-3.3

```
    import re, math
    equation = input("Enter your quadratic equation:  ")
    coef = re.compile('\s*(\d*)\s*x\^2\s*\+\s*(\d*)\s*x\s*\+\s*(\d*)\s*')
    a,b,c = coef.match(equation).group(1,2,3)
```

Now I understand where the error is coming from but my issue is why is it a non-type. The same code was working the other day and I just can't figure it out. I have looked but I can't seem to find out why but I'm sure someone on here will be able to. Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: Clearly the result of `coef.match(equation)` is `NoneType`. So make sure you input something that does match the pattern.

Comment: Then it won't match because you don't support `"-"`s.

Comment: I must have changed the code or something in that case then because as I say it worked before. How would I make it support "-" as the code I am using was recommended to me on here so I don't really know how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might work.

```
# UNTESTED
coef = re.compile('\s*(\d*)\s*x\^2\s*[+-]\s*(\d*)\s*x\s*[+-]\s*(\d*)\s*')
```

Note, I replaced `\+` with `[+-]`. Also, you might want to capture the operators because they affect the sign of `b` and `c`.